# Opening a new page in the program in vb.net (hreflink)

Tags: vb.net

how to do that when you clicked the button opened the generated youtube page?

My button code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim buttonele As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In buttonele
        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("id") = "likeText" Then
            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

And code button in website:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Ei9.png)

```
in <a href="linkkk"> there is already a generated link to yt
in <a class="likeClick" href="#"> - # generates new links
```

after clicking on the button, nothing happens.
I need that after clicking the page generated in this link opens:

```
<a href="https://href.li/?http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-MRipzqM5Y">
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is uncler, but either way, either click the video button or Webbrowser.Navigate("webpage url")

Comment: look at the picture: http://pl.tinypic.com/r/1621k0m/9 how to open youtube by button "like"? my code not work